# CollectionView/ListView with nested expandable CollectionView/ListView Items

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am making an app that has a comment section, however each comment can be replied to independently and those also replied to (and so on).

This essentially gives me threads that can branch off specific comments.

I want to be able to click a comment, and expand a all comments attached to it in a new list.

I currently have a collection view that contains my comments.

```
  <CollectionView x:Name="lvComments" BackgroundColor="#25405E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Comment}"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Margin="25,1,25,0"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    FontFamily="Font_11"
                                    TextColor="White" 
                                    BackgroundColor="Green" 
                                    >
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="Label_Tapped" />
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

However this only shows the top level comment. I am thinking the best way to do this would be to add a new collection view or  list view to the item row in the Label_Tapped() function below the label.

Something like this -

```
Comment 1
   ->Comment 1.1
   ->Comment 1.2
      ->Comment 1.2.1
```

I am not sure whether this is recommended or even possible as I don't know how to add new items to an existing element programmatically during run time.

What would be the best approach here? Are there any components that exists already that do this?

Comment: I believe the right way is to implement your owb ```RecyclerView.Adapter``` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter. Current implementations are not designed for this, I doubted you can get a smooth experience even if succeed to build it up on existing implementation. However before start your own custom implementation, I would advise to do a research first on github and tutorials: it is not a rare case, some companies already did it and might share code]tech articles as a part of their marketing&sales activities.

Comment: An alternative approach is to fake it. Have a single list of items, but each item's viewmodel has an "indent depth" (that becomes a left margin). When you "expand" an item, insert after it its children, adding 1 to depth. When you collapse an item, remove its children (and any children they have).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a complex Expandable CollectionView/ListView with a sub CollectionView/ListView which allows you to Expand and Collapse items via a simple click.in .Net Maui.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvComments"  IsGroupingEnabled="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">  
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                        <DataTemplate>  
                            <ViewCell>  
                                  <Label Text="{Binding SubComment}"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Margin="25,1,25,0"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    FontFamily="Font_11"
                                    TextColor="White" 
                                    BackgroundColor="Green" 
                                   / >
                               </HorizontalStackLayout>  
                            </ViewCell>  
                        </DataTemplate>  
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>  
                        <DataTemplate>  
                            <ViewCell>  
                                <Grid>  
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Comment}"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    Margin="25,1,25,0"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    FontFamily="Font_11"
                                    TextColor="White" 
                                    BackgroundColor="Green" 
                                    />
                               
                                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>  
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference currentPage}, Path=BindingContext.RefreshItemsCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />  
                                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>  
                                </Grid>  
                            </ViewCell>  
                        </DataTemplate>  
     </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>  
</ListView>
```